# A question on Husserl and animals in relation to psychology

Tags: psychology, husserl, phenomenolgy

This is from Husserl's Phenomenology which he wrote for the Encyclopedia Britannica:

> The scientific investigation of the bodies of animals fits within this area. By contrast, however, if the psychic aspect of the animal world is to become the topic of investigation, the first thing we have to ask is how far, in parallel with the pure science of nature, a pure psychology is possible. Obviously, purely psychological research can be done to a certain extent. To it we owe the basic concepts of the psychical according to the properties essential and specific to it. These concepts must be incorporated into the others, into the psychophysical foundational concepts of psychology.

Why must these concepts be incorporated into the psychophysical foundational concepts of psychology - what happens if we don't?

Comment: If we don't we won't have a comprehensive theory of animal behavior that incorporates both psychic and physical aspects.

Comment: A key sentence here is "we owe the basic concepts of the psychical according to the properties essential and specific to it", so Husserl apparently holds *psychical* essentialism and he puts certain such properties on the same footing as scientific properties of the verifiable *physical*, which is a controversial view given modern eliminativism of phil. of mind. Indeed, contemporary eliminativists such as Churchland would be extremely skeptical for the ability to incorporate psychical concepts into a grand unified psychophysical foundation of psychology if this is ever achievable...

Comment: Thanks double knot!

Comment: Just to make sure I follow you... First of all that akward sentence is saying that the possibility of the purely psychological research is indebted to certain properties of the basic psychical concepts.

Comment: These concepts, since they are essential to psychology are foundational to psychology and so should be put alongside other concepts that are also foundational otherwise it would be absurdity.

Comment: sounds on the right track... for example, the famous pair of noesis and noema are such essential psychical concepts in Husserl's system, and in ancient Vasubandhu's system has two other concepts to form a core group of four...

Answer (score 1):

The history of psychology has principally been the science of being mean to rats..

It sounds like he is expressing doubt about our access to the interiority of animals (top-down psychology, as opposed to ground-up neuroscience). I presume he means something like, we must go beyond Behaviourism. It's not a very clear paragraph..

For Husserl, animals were an important area of consideration.  He saw there as being two modes to investigate consciousness, internal reflections, and (external) comparison. He considered investigating consciousness to be in the phenomenological mode, as contrasted to the natural, because it must be engaged with understanding something abstract or universal about the necessary logical structure of being a subject.

He contrasted 'to be a body'  (in German: Leibsein) and 'what it is to have a body' (Körperhaben), the lived body and the embodied mind, but saw their essential unity as a neccessary grounding for either to arise - perception and sensing as coarising. Considering animals then is a way to examine human consciousness through contrast. He saw the child and the animal as anomolous minds, with differences to be contrasted. He called animals 'abnormal' or even 'degenerate' humans (yeah, Nazi era language, though he was Jewish & died in 1938), but we have to see in this the stark contrast with a Cartesian view of an essential distinction of humans with animals. Because he saw animals as sharing in the transcendental subjectivity that was the basis of his phenomenological method, but as lacking language that is the basis for human *intersubjectivity*.

So, the psychophysical foundation for Husserl is the deep unity of mind and embodiment, psychology alone failing to understand the impacts of brain structure and chemistry, but science that doesn't investigate subjectivity and interior experience also missing something fundamental; both arising together from one foundation (nb, we have no access to phenomena unfiltered  by subjectivities, mind is always involved).

Comment: *history of behaviorist psychology. There's that great scene with Stephen Fry in the movie IQ with "Einstein" looking on with Poldosky that seems to capture the spirit of behaviorism from a broader view.

Comment: +1 For comparing Husserl's ethological precepts with those of the Cartesian animal-as-automaton.